# How much resources does PHP waste on irrelevant code, if any?

Tags: php, memory, resources

This is not a question about principles or common coding procedures, it is a question about how PHP processes code, or more precisely, *doesn't* process code that it should ignore, in the name of better understanding how PHP works

Scenario 1:

```
if (1==2) { echo rand(0,99); }
```

Obviously, the code above will not have any output, and that's not what the question is about; but rather, about whether or not PHP even *considers* making any output. As PHP goes through the page, does it entirely skip the code assigned to the failed if-check, or does it get allocated any sort of resources beyond simply what the filesize does?

Scenario 2:

```
if (1==2) { for ($x = 0; $x <= 999999; $x++) { echo rand(0,99); } }
```

Similar to scenario 1 but with a key difference to clarify the point, considering that 1==2 is always going to be false, does this code use any more resources than the previous one or will they both be equally "cheap" to process? Or are there any "hidden" actions that add up even if the code in the loop is as minimal as this?

Scenario 3:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 999999; $x++) { if (1==2) { echo rand(0,99); } }
```

Now, this one should see a false statement a million times, but how significant is that really in terms of resources? Will it keep checking if 1 is 2 or does PHP "learn" from the first time it checks? And does it spend any resources beyond that, or is a simple if-check like this inside a loop the only thing PHP will process? Will it "read" `echo rand(0,99);` a million times, even though 1 is not 2?

Scenario 4:

```
for ($x = 0; $x <= 999999; $x++) { if (1==2) { for ($x = 0; $x <= 999999; $x++) { echo rand(0,99); } } }
```

Finally, a combination of them all, will this example be a massive loop-in-a-loop-level of resource wasting or will the inner loop be completely ignored from processing? In other words, will 1!=2 cause PHP to *entirely skip* processing the inner loop, or will it waste memory on code that it should ignore? And how different is this scenario compared to the previous three in terms of processing and resources?

Thanks in advance for any PHP and memory-usage expertise on the matter, it is my hope that the answer to this question will bring better understanding about how PHP processes code to me and others

**EDIT**:
Another somewhat relevant example would be that of having a large amount of comments within a loop compared to outside of it; would comments inside of a loop affect performance differently *in any way* (regardless of how "unnoticeable" you might consider it to be) *than* the same amount of comments outside of the loop?

Comment: Why don't you ... try it and see? Put something that will write a file or update a database or create a session inside the test code and see if it happens. Time the page load with browser dev tools and see if the loop slows it down. See if the server/php processes take more memory.

Comment: You can also use `microtime()` function before and after code blocks to make manual unit testing, while you check your OS's performance monitor.

Comment: Anyway, like @DaOgre answered, every language engine (maybe with exception of some esoteric ones) works on pure **logic**, so there is no reason to go visit false cases inside if statements. *If false, goodbye, adios, next line please*.

Comment: This question is way more interesting than might be on first sight: maybe sombody can give an answer to this question that involves the possible bytecode caching (Zend Optimizer/APC) that is involved.

Answer (score 3):

1 & 2) Everything inside these if blocks is not evaluated

3) PHP doesnt learn anything, it will perform 1 million if checks.  This isn't significant but it's not insignificant either.  As one commenter suggested, try it and see the page time hit.

4) This generates the same amount of processing as #3

Comment: That's a good straight answer, actually (even being OP's examples plain obvious). +1

Comment: Although the code inside the `if` blocks is not evaluated, it **is** parsed. The entire script is parsed and turned into an internal format before any evaluation occurs.

Comment: @Barmar and how would you interpret "processing" as stated by OP? Evaluation or parsing? Because now I'm thinking, if literally, it's both.

Comment: Sure but those loops aren't evaluated, so the fact that they're for loops doesnt add more processing when it's turned into bytecode compared to any other operation.

Comment: @AlanMachado The OP asks if it "allocates any resources". It allocates the memory for the parsed body of the `if`. And it also takes a tiny amount of time to parse the body.

Comment: So, bigger the `else` statement, say, even if never evaluated... bigger the allocation, even irrelevant bytes of it.